# Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in wp-includes/post.php in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am using wordpress version 5.32 and elementor plugin (2.8)

While i am trying to customize and publish it raise an issue like:

```
<b>Notice</b>
: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object in 
<b>/wordpress/wp-includes/post.php</b> 
on line <b>6534</b>
<br />
```

Line 6534:

```
function update_post_cache( &$posts ) {
    if ( ! $posts ) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        wp_cache_add( $post->ID, $post, 'posts' );
    }
}
```

and the change not geting updated in the website.

Disabling the elementor plugin will resolve this problem. How can i fix this issue with elementor plugin.

Comment: Do you change some code?

Comment: No php code change did yet.

Comment: First tip, unistall plugin and re-install it else post code of line 6534

Comment: uninstall and re-install doesn't solved the issue.  <br/>  Here i am pating the code of line 6534:   ``` function update_post_cache( &$posts ) {
    if ( ! $posts ) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        wp_cache_add( $post->ID, $post, 'posts' );
    }
}```

Comment: update the question not here please

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$post->ID
```

you can use:

```
$post['ID']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 function update_post_cache( &$posts ) {
    if (!$posts) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        wp_cache_add( $post['ID'], $post,'posts');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :
I had a siliar issue, I noticed that in de database, the table `wp_posts` had entries with the `ID` that had a value of `0`.

I deleted those entrys and added an `AUTO_INCREMENT` (that for some reason was not set) to the `ID` row of that table

Comment: why do you think this might be related to the issue at hand? Where you getting the same error?